# Could not find function "textstat_frequency"

Tags: r, quanteda, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to figure a solution for this error. There was a post a few years back, but it never came to a solution. Let me try to provide more details:

Here is the error

```
textstat_freq(testing.dfm, n = 10, groups = "ByNmbr")
Error in textstat_freq(testing.dfm, n = 10, groups = "ByNmbr") : 
  could not find function "textstat_freq"
```

There are errors when installing quanteda.
I am not sure if these are relevant.
Here is my installog:

```
install.packages("quanteda")
also installing the dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
                  binary     source needs_compilation
RcppArmadillo 0.11.2.4.0 0.11.4.0.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/quanteda_3.2.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4191430 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/w5/hsxqtj6n32qbq0j4409h6kbm0000gn/T//Rtmp6seSBH/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘RcppArmadillo’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.11.4.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1369973 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... yes
checking for clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -E
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... (cached) yes
checking whether clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 option to enable C++11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether we have a suitable tempdir... /var/folders/w5/hsxqtj6n32qbq0j4409h6kbm0000gn/T
checking whether R CMD SHLIB can already compile programs using OpenMP... no
checking whether g++ version is sufficient... almost
configure: WARNING: Compiler self-identifies as being compliant with GNUC extensions but is not g++.
checking for macOS... found
checking for macOS Apple compiler... not found
checking for clang compiler... found
checking for OpenMP compatible version of clang... not found
configure: WARNING: OpenMP unavailable and turned off.
checking LAPACK_LIBS... R-supplied partial LAPACK found
configure: WARNING: Some complex-valued LAPACK functions may not be available
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I../inst/include  -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I../inst/include  -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include  -I../inst/include  -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0/12.0.1 -L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0/12.0.1'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/w5/hsxqtj6n32qbq0j4409h6kbm0000gn/T/Rtmp6seSBH/downloaded_packages’
```

The quanteda version check:

```
> library(quanteda)
Package version: 3.2.3
Unicode version: 14.0
ICU version: 70.1
Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
```

(This is a dummy text, this is a dummy text as stack won't let me post if my post is mostly code and I have no idea what else to add ,This is a dummy text,This is a dummy text,This is a dummy text,This is a dummy text,This is a dummy text,This is a dummy text).

Comment: the relevant bit is `ld: library not found for -lgfortran` . There are a few posts on how to install fortran on a mac. Then try again.

Comment: @user20650 thanks for the advice! I installed gfortran for Monterey. Installed quanteda (and quanteda.textstats) again and the installing now comes without any errors and does not mention "installing the dependency ‘RcppArmadillo" anymore. Unfortunately I still get the "could not find function "textstat_freq" error.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [github](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda) it is `textstat_frequency` instead of `textstat_freq`:

> quanteda.textstats: statistics for textual data, namely the
> textstat_*() functions, split with the v3 release

Let's try installing the `quanta.textstats` and `quanteda` packages to use the `textstat_frequency` function. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(quanteda.textstats)
library(quanteda)
#> Package version: 3.2.3
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dfm_inaug <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, Year <= 1826) %>% 
  dfm(remove = stopwords('english'), remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 10, verbose = FALSE)
#> Warning: 'dfm.corpus()' is deprecated. Use 'tokens()' first.
#> Warning: '...' should not be used for tokens() arguments; use 'tokens()' first.
#> Warning: 'remove' is deprecated; use dfm_remove() instead

features_dfm_inaug <- textstat_frequency(dfm_inaug, n = 100)

# Sort by reverse frequency order
features_dfm_inaug$feature <- with(features_dfm_inaug, reorder(feature, -frequency))

ggplot(features_dfm_inaug, aes(x = feature, y = frequency)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the binary versions only of **quanteda**, **quanteda.textstats**, and their dependencies (e.g., **RcppArmadillo**) if you are not able to set up the tools you need to compile source packages.
2. Try this:

   ```r
   library("quanteda")
   library("quanteda.textstats")

   # verify that the function now works
   example("textstat_frequency")
   ```

Comment: Runs both without issues and dives me a bunch of examples for the 2nd option, but I am still geting the "could not find function "textstat_freq"" error. Same btw for other quanteda functions (e.g. " could not find function "textplot_xray"")

Comment: RTFM. There is no function named `textstat_freq()`. All plot functions are now in **quanteda.textplots**. https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-and-additions-3

Comment: Thanks for the reminder but I have obviously installed all packages of quanteda from the CAN repository i.e. quanteda, quanteda.textmodels, quanteda.textplots, quanteda.textstats.